# Find and Replace String but Keep a few Characters In Their Place

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013, replace, find

I have a string such as

```
thisIsAString.property = thisIsAMethod.doThis(yyy);
```

That I want to replace with

```
thisIsAString.aDifferentProperty = ((thisIsAString.property = thisIsAMethod.doThis(yyy)) != string.Empty) ? true : false;
```

Where **yyy** will remain the same during the replace but will change for each document in my project.

So that in my Find and Replace toolbar the boxes will contain the following:

**Find what:** `thisIsAString.property = thisIsAMethod.doThis(SOME REGEX??);`
**Replace with:** `thisIsAString.aDifferentProperty = ((thisIsAString.property = thisIsAMethod.doThis(REGEX TO KEEP WHAT WAS IN HERE IN 'FIND WHAT')) != string.Empty) ? true : false;`
**Look in:** `Current Project`

And I would **Replace All**

Can I do this in Visual Studio 2013 using *Edit -> Find and Replace -> Replace in Files*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the part you want to keep and use a back reference to put it back:

```
Find: thisIsAString.property = thisIsAMethod.doThis\((.*?)\);
Replace: thisIsAString.aDifferentProperty = ((thisIsAString.property = thisIsAMethod.doThis(\1)) != string.Empty) ? true : false;
```

The important bits here are;

- use `(.*?)` to *capture* the "YYY"
- use `\1`, which refers to "group 1", to include it in the replacement
- escape the literal brackets in the find term

Comment: This worked but I would place a `\\`` in my string. Using `$1` instead of `\1` fixed this.

Comment: Would `(.*?)` change if there would only be digits for YYY?

Comment: @gh0st OK `$1` - I'm not familiar with Visual Studio, and there are two flavours of back reference; backslash and dollar. Regarding digits. `.*?` will match everything up to the next bracket. If you wanted to restrict your matches to only digits, change `.*?` to `\d+`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex replacement I could come up with:

```
(?m)^\s*(?<astr>\w+)\.(?<prop>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<mthd>\w+)\.(?<dothis>\w+)\((?<inbr>.*?)\);\s*\r?$
```

And the replacement string is:

```
${astr}.aDifferentProperty = ((${astr}.${prop} = ${mthd}.${dothis}(${inbr})) != string.Empty) ? true : false;
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5Cs*(%3F%3Castr%3E%5Cw%2B)%5C.(%3F%3Cprop%3E%5Cw%2B)%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*(%3F%3Cmthd%3E%5Cw%2B)%5C.(%3F%3Cdothis%3E%5Cw%2B)%5C((%3F%3Cinbr%3E.*%3F)%5C)%3B%5Cs*%5Cr%3F%24&i=thisIsAString.property%20%3D%20thisIsAMethod.doThis(yyy)%3B&r=%24%7Bastr%7D.aDifferentProperty%20%3D%20((%24%7Bastr%7D.%24%7Bprop%7D%20%3D%20%24%7Bmthd%7D.%24%7Bdothis%7D(%24%7Binbr%7D))%20!%3D%20string.Empty)%20%3F%20true%20%3A%20false%3B&o=m)

In case `\w+` is not matching, adjust it by using a character class, e.g. `[\w.]` to also match a dot.